# Trying to Force 2 digits in Oracle APEX using TO_CHAR; getting 'Unable to bind' Error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

ORACLE APEX 4.2

I am working with Length and duration values and I'm using 3 integer fields to store hours, minutes, and seconds (Datetime didn't work for calculations). Everything works with my calculations, but I am Having trouble concatenating the values in the format `HH:MM:SS` to display in a report.

```
SELECT (Length_hour || ':' || Length_Min || ':' || Length_SEC) as "Length"
FROM TBL_VIDEO
```

The above works but gives me `H:M:S`

I'm now trying to force the first digit using `TO_CHAR()` like this:

```
SELECT (Length_hour || ':' || Length_Min || ':' || Length_SEC) as "Length", TO_CHAR(Length_Min, '01') as "Temp"
FROM TBL_VIDEO
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Unable to bind 01 verify length of item is 30 bytes or less. Use v() syntax to reference items longer than 30 bytes. ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist

It seems as if it expects '01' to be and item to be referenced, but that's just the desired format as per [TO_CHAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

**Any ideas why this is happening and how I can achieve my format?**

Comment: The format mask should be either `'00'` or `'09'` if you want leading zeros, not `'01'`

Comment: I tried both, Same result in any case.

Comment: The error message implies that it having issues with bind values, try replacing your colons (`:`) with chr(58) for example: SELECT (Length_hour || chr(58) || Length_Min || chr(58) || Length_SEC) as "Length" FROM TBL_VIDEO

Comment: TO_CHAR(Length_Min, '01') fails in isolation. The ':' works fine when TO_CHAR in not added

Comment: What's the actual query you are using when you encounter the above error?  You've provided a query that you say works, but not the query that does not work.

Comment: It's a needlessly long query, but I'm basically trying to create another field...I've updated my original post, but left out other fields and joins that are not relevant

Comment: Datetime type DO work for calculations. There is also `timestamp` type. Which kind of calculations do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Approaching this from a completely different direction try this:

```
SELECT (Length_hour || ':' || Length_Min || ':' || Length_SEC) as "Length"
     , regexp_substr(
           to_char(
               numtodsinterval(
                   Length_hour*3600+Length_Min*60+Length_SEC
                 , 'second'))
         , '[^+0 ]([^.]*)'
       ) as "Temp"
FROM TBL_VIDEO
```

In this code the second column converts your numeric columns to an interval of type day to second, converts it to a string of the form `+00000000 00:00:00.0000000` then uses a regular expression to pull out just the non fractional time portion (plus any days <> 0).  The regexp_substr does expect that the interval is a positive and not negative value.

Comment: Gives me the same error: `Unable to bind FM00 verify length of item is 30 bytes or less. Use v() syntax to reference items longer than 30 bytes.`